# Restrict Pages From Non Admin Users (PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am developing a website that requires several user types. I have been able to redirect the user types to different homages based on user roll/type after they login. However, I need to restrict the Admin portion of the site to just admin role types. I am storing a "1" or "2" into the database based on user type/role. I am using the "session_start" and "session_is_registered" to check the user information. What do I need to add to this code to restrict users with a role type of "1" from seeing the page.

```
session_start();
if(!session_is_registered(username)){
header('Location: ../admin/index.php');
}
```

Comment: `session_is_registered()` is [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-is-registered.php).

Comment: you can use ENUM type in database field, and check the role with require ing a php file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Store the users role in a session variable

```
$_SESSION["role"]=1;
```

or

```
$_SESSION["role"]=2;
```

depending on the stored user information.

Then when you check the permissions, you just check this variable:

```
if($_SESSION["role"]==2){
  header('Location: ../admin/index.php');
} else {
  echo "you need the admin role to view this page!";
}
```

**Another advice:**
It would be better to check the permissions in ../admin/index.php and redirect back to the default page if the user does not have the admin role. Otherwise users might be able to directly browse to ../admin/index.php if they know the URL.

Comment: You have a typo; `$_SESSION["role"}=2;` should be `$_SESSION["role"]=2;`. Notice the `]`.

Comment: So I am still having issues. I need to hide all admin pages from anyone that is not an admin. All users are required to log in to the site. I have the redirect setup so people with a "roletype" of 1 go the admin and "2" go to the home page. I need to restrict access for "2" to admin pages.

Answer (score 0):

Just nest your if statement. If they are an admin, direct them to an admin page otherwise send them somewhere else.